# How to use typography of material angular dart components with Dart 2?

Tags: dart, material-design, angular-components, angular-dart

I wanted to use the material typography in the components with the help of material angular_dart components. How can I do that?
app_component.html

```
<section class="layout">
    <h1 class="headline">The headline goes here!</h1>
    <h2 class="sub-headline">Lorem ipsum is placeholder text commonly used in the graphic, print, and publishing industries for previewing layouts and visual mockups.</h2>
    <div class="body-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</section>
```

app_component.scss

```
@import 'package:angular_components/css/material/material';

:host {

}

.headline {

}

.sub-headline {
}

.body-text {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a bunch of mixins you can use [here:](https://github.com/dart-lang/angular_components/blob/master/angular_components/lib/css/_typography_material.scss)

For your example:

```
@import 'package:angular_components/css/material/material';

.headline {
  @include mat-font-headline;
}

.sub-headline {
  @include mat-font-subhead;
}

.body-text {
  @include mat-font-body;
}
```

[image]

Comment: which mixins do I need to import to make the code work.

Comment: The import is the same one you had in your question above. It collects the common variables and mixins. The specific mixins are shown in the code with the include.

Comment: Added a screenshot of what it looks like. It is working for me. Do you have the Roboto font loaded? You need a link tag like this in the head: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">